# Glue for internal rubber seals on uPVC windows

Tags: adhesive, pvc, rubber

I have some double glazed uPVC casement windows, the interior seal around the sash has come loose in some places.

Unlike some other windows, these seals don't clip into the uPVC profile, but are instead glued.

What kind of glue should I use to re-attach the seals?

[image: Location of seal]

[image: Surfaces need adhering]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see working here with rubber and vinyl would be cyanoacrylate (super glue). There may be other options, but that gets into product recommendation territory.

I'd use a gel type that will stay put and not flow everywhere. Take the sashes out to a clean, stable work area if possible, and consider masking sensitive areas first.

Do be sure that you're actually seeing pull-off and not tearing of something that's set into a channel, for example. Replacing the entire seal in the latter case may be the only reliable option.

Comment: Appears to have worked. I ended up using the non-gel variety - it made it easier to use a tiny amount and spread it along